# Error on Timer?

Tags: android, timer

I would like to ask why is that my code gives me error now? I just copy it from my timer activity only that works fine to my other activity and suddenly it gives me an error?

here's my code

*LogCat

```
01-28 16:41:34.900: W/dalvikvm(9387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164a8a8)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at com.thesis.logipic.Gameplay$MyCount.onTick(Gameplay.java:2776)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-28 16:41:34.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 16:41:36.152: D/AudioTrack(9387): audiotrack 0x52b30c10 stop done
```

*Timer Activity

http://pastebin.com/7ybnTm9R

*My Activity

http://pastebin.com/bAEszRpL

Comment: `NullPointerException` at Gameplay.java:2776 ... what line is it?

Comment: Copy this line `Gameplay.java:2776` here

Comment: o yah the line 2776 is " tvTimer.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));"